# Disable xdebug trace with xdebug_disable()

Tags: php, xdebug

How do I check programmatically if `xdebug` is installed so that I can call  `xdebug_disable()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(function_exists('xdebug_disable')) 
{ 
   xdebug_disable(); 
}
```